# Data binding not changing when using a formatter on SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to use a formatter with the values of `DateRangeSelection` but when I apply the formatter the date binding is not working anymore.

```
<DateRangeSelection 
        id="DateRangeTest2" 
        dateValue="{path: '/FROM_DATE', formatter: '.dateFormatter'}"
        secondDateValue="{path: '/END_DATE', formatter: '.dateFormatter'}"
        valueFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
        displayFormat="{/DATE_STYLE}"
/>
```

Also, here is a JSFiddle to see the problem: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a1x0vnsc/)

Comment: By "date binding" do you mean letting the framework manipulate the stored model value via two-way binding?

Comment: Do the dates need to be strings? You could just use the built in types instead of a formatter: https://jsfiddle.net/0u6x1pbg/1/

Comment: When using a formatter you lose the 2-way binding with the model. You should use the binding constrains to format your value (https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/topic/e1ddc69c01474faf830a522db8c9238a)

Comment: @Marc yeah, dates need to be strings, and also in your example the date style is not working (try with long e.g.)